# c++ "interface"-like classes similar to Java?

Tags: java, c++, class, interface

In Java, you can define an interface as a class with no actual code implementation, but only to define the methods that a class must implement. Those types can be passed as parameters to methods and returned from methods. In C++, a pure virtual class can't be used as a parameter or return type, from what I can tell. Any way to mimic Java's interface classes?

I have a string class in C++, and several subclasses for different encodings (like UTFxxx, ISOxxx, etc) that derive from the base string class. However, since there are so many different encodings, the base class has no meaningful implementation. But it would serve well as an interface if I could handle it as its own object and calls to that object would call on the correct subclass it was inherited to.

Comment: You certainly *can* use an abstract class as a parameter or return type... could you show some code please?

Comment: Haven't implemented the pure virtual base class yet. I am reading several articles that discuss what you can and cannot do with pure virtual classes. Using them as a stand-alone type for arguments doesn't seem to be one of them.

Comment: Well, not by value, but you certainly can by pointer or by reference.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionఠ_ఠ Concepts aren't really like interfaces much at all.  Interfaces operate at run-time and are concerned on polymorphism, while concepts were a compile time feature and are all about templates.  The only real similarity is that they specify some sort of "contract" with using code, which isn't anything special really.

Comment: @MichaelPrice Well, what is *closer* to the idea of interfaces in C++?

Comment: @NullUserExceptionఠ_ఠ Pure abstract classes.  It is a representation of a contract with calling code that contains absolutely no implementation (save a virtual function table and basically empty constructor and destructor).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use a pure virtual class by value, but you can pass it around by pointer or by reference.  This includes the ability to pass it around wrapped within a smart pointer type such as `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr`.

You should also make sure that you mark the destructor on the interface with the `virtual` keyword to prevent potential memory leaks.

Comment: Say I create an object that is declared as the pure virtual class type, but in fact it is a subclass that is not pure virtual, can I make calls to that object and pass it to a method, return its type from a method?

Comment: Well, you cannot create objects of the pure virtual class type... it is after all abstract.  `void func(Interface *); Interface * i = new Impl(); func(i);` is perfectly valid.  You can also return the interface by reference or by a pointer.

Comment: Java is the same as C++ in this regard; you cannot create an instance of an interface in Java, and you can only pass them by reference.

Answer (score 3):

A pure-virtual class can be used as a return type iff you only use reference or pointer.

In fact, in Java, `Interface foo = Implementer();` is equivalent to `Interface* foo = Implementer();` and `implements Foo` is `public virtual Foo`.

Here is a Java example:

```
interface Foo {
    public void doFoo();
}
class Bar implements Foo {
    public void doFoo() { }
}
```

Its C++ counterpart:

```
struct Foo {
    virtual void doFoo() = 0;
    virtual ~Foo() { }
};
class Bar : public virtual Foo {
public:
    virtual void doFoo() { }
    virtual ~Bar() { }    
};
```

Rightly, C++ will whine about incomplete type if you use `Foo foo;`. Using `Foo& foo`, `Foo* foo`, or `smart_pointer<Foo> foo` is what is required.

In this example `smart_pointer` can be `scoped_ptr`, `unique_ptr`, or `shared_ptr`, depending on if you want

- simply a smart pointer that `delete()s` on destruction
- a smart pointer with move semantics
- a smart pointer that does reference counting

Note that boost smart pointers, should you use them, use `get()`/`reset()` semantics for getting and setting the pointer value.

Comment: You mean `Interface * foo = new Implementer();` ?

Comment: No. If you look at the java snippet immediately to the left, you can assume that `Implementer()` is a function returning `Interface`, hence `Implementer` is of type `Interface *()`. I did not make the implication of allocation - only the fact that a pointer is returned was stated.

Comment: I see.  Very good.  Although I'd argue it would be a simpler example to avoid a factory method.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly use a class like an interface, but it's not a construct of the language, it's just a class with only pure virtual methods. Remember, interfaces were just how Java did multiple inheritance without all the tricky problems (two copies of a grandparent class, multiple variables with the same name, etc)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the definition of interface in Google C++ Style:

A class is a pure interface if it meets the following requirements:

- It has only public pure virtual ("= 0") methods and static methods (but see below for destructor).
- It may not have non-static data members.
- It need not have any constructors defined. If a constructor is provided, it must take no arguments and it must be protected.
- If it is a subclass, it may only be derived from classes that satisfy these conditions and are tagged with the Interface suffix.

An interface class can never be directly instantiated because of the pure virtual method(s) it declares. To make sure all implementations of the interface can be destroyed correctly, the interface must also declare a virtual destructor (in an exception to the first rule, this should not be pure). See Stroustrup, The C++ Programming Language, 3rd edition, section 12.4 for details.

Take a look at Google C++ Style Guide, section "Multiple Inheritance" and "Interface". http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml